# .on('click') VS 'selector.click

Tags: jquery

Maybe I'm losing my mind or maybe I missed the memo. I ALWAYS use `$(selector).click` for any and all click events unless I'm interacting with elements added to the DOM after the fact. In which case I used something like `$(closest permanent parent).on('click',selector`.

I see tons of people on here that just use .`on()` for EVERYTHING. Am I missing the benefits of `.on()` or something? It seems incorrect to me. I've read the documentation and I see no reason to use `.on()` vs `.click()`.

Is it strictly preference when interacting with static DOM elements?

**EDIT**

Apparently I was unclear. I understand the use of `.on()` for dynamically generated elements. My question was `Why use it for static elements`?

Comment: So why is javascript in the tags?

Comment: Apologies. I'll remove

Comment: `.click(handler)` is just a shortcut for `.on('click',handler)`. Internally it will use `.on()` method in all case, for delegated event or not

Comment: `.on` encourages event delegation

Comment: I just feel like `.on` is incorrect and unnecessary when event delegation is not required.

Comment: @Leeish this is not the case, for consistency in code it is better to use .on() syntax and btw would avoid jquery to parse .click() to .on() method

Comment: So, we're thinking jQuery included `.click` to help us be lazy. I can buy that.

Comment: @Leeish some custom jquery implementation don't include it, and for example, for onload event, shortcut using .load() is deprecated

Comment: @ManofSnow well jquery is made using js

Comment: @Huangism True, very true, but if you know javascript you technically don't know JQuery if you've never heard of it.

Comment: @BothOfYou I really wanted to understand a practical application of using `.on()` in jQuery for static DOM elements and zzzzBov provided the best answer.

Comment: @ManofSnow but if you know jquery it doesn't mean you don't know js. I think it makes sense for the OP to put the js tag on it since it gives it more visibility. I would assume OP knows both since he put the tag there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.click()` is defined* as:

```
jQuery.fn.click = function( data, fn ) {
    return arguments.length > 0 ?
        this.on( 'click', null, data, fn ) :
        this.trigger( 'click' );
```

`click` is simply a partial of the `on` function, so for performance `.on()` is slightly faster. That said, the difference is negligible and that's not the actual reason I prefer `on` over `click`.

The real reason I stick with `on` over `click` is for maintainability. Oftentimes I'll start a plugin by binding an `.on('click', ...)` method, and later change it to `.on('widgetaction', ...)` event which is triggered by a click, but may also be triggered by a `keypress` or any other relevant event.

Sticking with the `.on()` function also means that I can easily go back and change from `.on('click', ...)` to `.on('click', selector, ...)` without significant effort.

In general it comes down to consistency, and I find that `.on()` is more consistent to use than `.click()`.

<sub>* I've modified the [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js) slightly to reference the click event specifically, reference jQuery v1.10.2 lines 7554-7564 for the original unmodified version.</sub>

Comment: I've never dug into the jQuery code to see this. Now that I do... well, that makes more sense. I think I might stop using `click()` soon.

Answer (score 1):

I basically use **`.on()`** event handler attachment for *dynamically generated elements* as a  kind delegated action.

**Updates:**

One more purpose is that you can **`attach/detach`** the event handler whenever you want using *.on/.off*

Answer (score 0):

You are right 
I prefer $(selector).click when I can. it's better for readablity

Answer (score 0):

The benefits of using `on()` besides a more sane API (imo) is that you can specify the following event handler

```
$(body).on('click', '.myDiv', function() {
    //do stuff here
});
```

Which does the same thing that the old and deprecated (depending on version of jQuery) `live()` did, that is, binding a click handler to an element that might get introduced in the future, also, the `on()` method works better since you now use the same unified API for all your event handlers, `on('hover'), on('mouseleave')` etc.

Comment: So you write all your click events like you just did above? Rather than simply `$('.myDiv').click`? How is that more sane? I understand for dynamic DOM elements which is why I wrote "`Is it strictly preference when interacting with static DOM elements?`"

Comment: @BillCriswell of course, but using `on()`, IMO, is much more sane that using `click()`, `.hover()` littered through out your code.

Comment: I prefer `on` as well. You two were editing as I was typing and things cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between using `$('selector').click()` and `$(body).on('click', 'selector')` is for dynamically added content (namely ajax). `on()` will work flawlessly without bugs to content added after the page has loaded, however `click()` will only work for content present on page load.

From the jQuery documentation:

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Lest not forget [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/): "Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future".

Answer (score 0):

The prefered method (For direct binding) is to use `.on()` instead of `.click()`.

Why you said? Because `.click()` is a shortcut to `.on()`. As you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L7559), the `.click()` function is only doing `element.on('click')`.

That being said. `.click()` only add 1 function call which mean not performance wise (even if it's just a little).

Comment: So, (I know it would be almost not noticeable) but `.click` would be bad for performance as well?

Comment: You will barely see any difference but yes, it is "slower".